# Implementation of sentiments in AEM 6.1

Tags: aem

I am enabling sentiments feature in my AEM community site. I am following steps from link[1] and used everything default, no configuration i have change but still I am unable to identify or filter my post in moderation[2]. If i am creating any post with negative and postive words, nothing i find when i apply filter.

Please help! How I can fix this?

Thank You in advance.

[1]. https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-1/administer/communities/moderate-ugc.html

[2]. http://localhost:4503/communities/moderation